# Grub Would Not Load without Live Usb

Tags: grub, kali-linux

I have installed kali linux from a live usb. I use dual boot option along with windows 7. After installation when grub is loading, it requires my usb along with it for successful loading. Else a missing device error is prompted and grub rescue option is shown. Can anyone help me with this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, Can you provide more information such as the error message and your Grub conifg?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have installed the grub to the USB drive. To fix this ,

From your booted linux system, open a terminal, then use the following commands :

> sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
>
> sudo update-grub

Replacing sdX with the actual drive, which will probably be sda, but use disk utility to double check if you are unsure.